# I want to delete the div element without changing any of the html code with js

Tags: javascript

I'm making a plugin with tempermonkey where I want to delete the `div` where the `button` is inside, but the `div` element doesn't have an `id`, only a class thats used for different elements. I only want to delete the one where the `button` is pressed. Thank you.

```
   // 1. Create the buttons
   var x;
   var y = document.getElementsByClassName("tasksAndMaterials__label");
     for (x = 0; x < y.length; x++) {
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        document.getElementsByClassName("tasksAndMaterials__label")[x].appendChild(br);
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.innerHTML = "Done";
        document.getElementsByClassName("tasksAndMaterials__label")[x].appendChild(btn);
    }
```

Comment: is the div's location always the exact same in the tree? if that's the case you could reference it by it's absolute index number(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing a div element will be a change to HTML, otherwise you might want to hide it.

But to remove an element from the DOM when it is clicked with a button, you can try:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tasksAndMaterials__label");

const remove = (element) =>{
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
};

elements.forEach((e)=>{
  let button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerText = "Done";
  button.addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
    remove(event.target.parentNode);
  });
  e.appendChild(button);
});
```

```html
<div class="tasksAndMaterials__label">some text 1</div>
<div class="tasksAndMaterials__label">some text 2</div>
<div class="tasksAndMaterials__label">some text 3</div>
```

You can try setting a variable containing an array of elements that can be removed. And then handle the click of the element to remove it with:

```
parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

It will remove any item with `class="tasksAndMaterials__label"` when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways to write your code (e.g. using a `for-loop`), but your code works, and for the purposes of instruction I will attempt to add to it instead of re-writing it. What you want is to add something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tasksAndMaterials__label")[x].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        this.style.display = "none";
```

For simplicity I've added the `.addEventListener` on the enclosing `div` rather than the button, which still works because of [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture) (i.e. the `click` event bubbles up to the enclosing element). Otherwise you can add the listener to the button itself and then target the `.parentNode` to hide or delete as necessary.

```js
var x;
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("tasksAndMaterials__label");
for (x = 0; x < y.length; x++) {
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementsByClassName("tasksAndMaterials__label")[x].appendChild(br);
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML = "Done";
    btn.style.color = "inherit"; 
    document.getElementsByClassName("tasksAndMaterials__label")[x].appendChild(btn);

    // add this line
    document.getElementsByClassName("tasksAndMaterials__label")[x].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        this.style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

```html
<div class ="tasksAndMaterials__label" style="color:blue"></div>
<div class ="tasksAndMaterials__label" style="color:black"></div>
<div class ="tasksAndMaterials__label" style="color:green"></div>
<div class ="tasksAndMaterials__label" style="color:red"></div>
```